# Interaction between two forms in c# (winforms) exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm developing a WinForm app.
I have two forms, form1 is the main window and form2 for settings.
I'm using this method for interaction between both forms:

code in form1:

```
   private void startForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
       frm.Show();
   }
   public void changeFontSize() //promenq razmera na shrifta
   {
       ...
   }
```

code in form2:

```
Form1 F1 = new Form1();

public Form2(Form1 aF1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    F1 = aF1;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    F1.changeFontSize();
}
```

When I close form2, it throws an exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Icon'.

in line

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer); // Clean up any resources being used.
    ...
```

in Form1.Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form F1 = new Form1();` field should be just `Form F1;`. Right now you are creating a new `Form1` instance which is not used at all (you overwrite the field in the constructor), and it will be disposed and collected non-deterministically by the GC.

It's most likely that this "hidden" instance is the one which creates the problem while being disposed.

You can also try moving that method inside the `Form.FormClosed` event handler, although it certainly seems to fit the `Dispose` method better.

Answer (score 0):

You should Dispose all resources on Form2 closing event.

Comment: That's not really true. If there is a `Dispose` method, as a part of the `IDisposable` interface, resposible for **disposing** objects, it's unlikely that one should dispose objects somewhere else. But in this case, I am unsure if that P/Invoke code actually releases some native resources (it probably does, based on the MSDN description).